# Get a list of dates between few dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are some quite similar questions, but not the same.
I have to solve the next problem: 
From table with such structure

```
| DATE_FROM  | DATE_TO    |
|------------|------------|
| 2010-05-17 | 2010-05-19 |
| 2017-01-02 | 2017-01-04 |
| 2017-05-01 | NULL       |
| 2017-06-12 | NULL       |
```

I need to get a list like the one below

```
| DATE_LIST  |
|------------|
| 2010-05-17 |
| 2010-05-18 |
| 2010-05-19 |
| 2017-01-02 |
| 2010-01-03 |
| 2010-01-04 |
| 2017-05-01 |
| 2017-06-12 |
```

How can I get it with SQL? SQL Server 2016.

Comment: What ahve you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is with a CROSS APPLY and an ad-hoc tally table

```
Select Date_List=B.D 
 from YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,[DATE_FROM],IsNull([DATE_TO],[DATE_FROM]))+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),[DATE_FROM]) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2 
             ) B
```

Returns

```
Date_List
2010-05-17
2010-05-18
2010-05-19
2017-01-02
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-05-01
2017-06-12
```

Comment: Note that master..spt_values is not documented and doesn't exist at all in Azure SQL database. A permanent user-defined number table would be better.

Comment: @DanGuzman Agreed,  Clearly a Tally/Calendar table would be the way to go. but that said, any table of respectible size would do.  There is no reference to any field name

Answer (score 3):

One method uses a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select date_from as date_list, date_to
      from t
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, date_from), date_to
      from cte
      where date_from < date_to
     )
select date_list
from cte;
```

By default, the recursive CTE is limited to a recursive depth of 100 (and then it returns an error).  That works for spans of up to 100 days.  You can remove the limit with `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but your SQL-code returns only 1-st column

Comment: @ЕвгенийМ . . . No, it would have generated an error.  I need to selectd the correct column.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could create the date range on the fly in your query, consider creating a permanent calendar table. This will provide better performance and can be extended with other attributes like day of week, fiscal quarter, etc. You can find many examples of loading such a table with an internet search.

Below is an example with 40 years of dates.

```
--example calendar table load script
CREATE TABLE dbo.Calendar(
    CalendarDate date NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Calendar PRIMARY KEY
    );
WITH 
     t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t64k AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b)
INSERT INTO dbo.Calendar WITH(TABLOCKX)
SELECT DATEADD(day, num, '20000101')
FROM t64k
WHERE DATEADD(day, num, '20000101') < '20400101'
GO
DECLARE @example TABLE(
     DATE_FROM date NOT NULL
    ,DATE_TO  date NULL
    );
GO

--example query
INSERT INTO @example VALUES
      ('2010-05-17', '2010-05-19')
    , ('2017-01-02', '2017-01-04')
    , ('2017-05-01', NULL)
    , ('2017-06-12', NULL)
SELECT
     c.CalendarDate
FROM @example AS e
JOIN dbo.Calendar AS c ON
    c.CalendarDate BETWEEN e.DATE_FROM AND COALESCE(e.DATE_TO, e.DATE_FROM);
```